# Mysql - changing autoincrement type from unsigned int to bigint - How long could it take?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have a table that has a primary key like `id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key`. The table has 100 mln rows and I estimated its size to 28GB.
I'd like to change primary key type to `unsinged bigint` because I reached the max value of the `unsigned int` but I need someone with more experience with mysql to tell me how long this query with the data I described could take ?

```
ALTER TABLE my-table MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Do you think it could take > 24h ?

Comment: *its size to 28GB .. Do you think it could take > 24h ?* The operation cannot be performed online and needs COPY strategy. Yes, this can be longer than a day easily... I'd recommend you to think about the table recreation with new structure and copying the data - this may be more fast. W/o indices other than PK the process (save to CSV - truncate - alter table - load data back) this should be ~5-6 hours.

Comment: It could take over 24 hours. This type of operation varies a lot. It depends partly on the speed of your hardware, and the concurrent load on the server. We don't know either of those things, so it's not possible to predict. Since it depends on the load on the specific server, it's not even accurate to try the operation on a test server with identical hardware.

Comment: If the disk is SSD (not HDD), it will be faster.  But, still, it will "take a long time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot afford any downtime and your table does not have triggers, please use pt-online-schema-change

Here is a script for you (call it change_column.sh)

```
BASE_FOLDER=<<Whatever Folder>>
CNF=${BASE_FOLDER}/my.cnf

DB=mydb
TB=mytable
ALT="MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT"

RUN_TYPE="dry_run"
RUN_MODE="--dry-run"
if [ "${1}" == "liverun" ] ; then
    RUN_TYPE="execute"
    RUN_MODE="--execute"
fi
LOG=${BASE_FOLDER}/ptosc_${RUN_TYPE}.log

OPTS="--pause-file=pause.txt"
OPTS="${OPTS} --max-load Threads_running=25,Threads_connected=70"
OPTS="${OPTS} --critical-load Threads_running=50,Threads_connected=100"
OPTS="${OPTS} --recursion-method=none --alter-foreign-keys-method=auto"
OPTS="${OPTS} --print ${RUN_MODE}"

pt-online-schema-change -F ${CNF} D=${DB},t=${TB} --alter="${ALT}" ${OPTS} >${LOG} 2>&1
```

Make sure your my.cnf for this run has this (as an example)

```
[client]
host     = Whatever FQDN or IP
user     = username
password = userpassword
```

Once set, execute a Dry Run to rehearse the change

```
./change_column.sh
```

This will run very quickly and produce a log file called ptosc_dry_run.log

If there are no errors, then run the real change in the background

```
nohup ./change_column.sh liverun &
```

Watch the ptosc_execute.log while it runs

```
watch "head -23 ptosc_execute.log ; echo ; tail ptosc_execute.log"
```

During the run, the table can still accept INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs, and SELECTs.

Please try this in a Staging or QA serve first to make sure you are satisfied with the operation and performance.

Comment: thanks ! I'll give it a try

Comment: If there any slowdowns in the middle of the business day, just run `touch pause.txt` and the copy operation will pause while the triggers will still update the temp table with INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs. When running this during quiet times, you can run `rm pause.txt` and the copy operation with pick up were it left off within 60 seconds. Also, the log file will give you a rough ETA as to how long it will run every 30 seconds. PLEASE LET US KNOW THE PROGRESS AND OUTCOME !!!